# Uml class diagram, what kind of relationship to use between composition, inheritance and association?

Tags: oop, inheritance, interface, uml, class-diagram

I need some help.
I'm writing class diagrams for my engineering software course and I have some doubt.
With few words, this app will send a trouble ticket about a gas loss e.g.
I have a class called "ManageTroublTicket" and I need some methods to delete or modify the ticket for example.

I already have a ticket class, so ManageTroubleTicket will have a ticket object as attribute, but for the rest?

Should I create a class for "DeleteTicket" and extends with ManageTroubleTIcket?
Like
Class DeleteTicket extends ManageTroubleTicket?

Or something like 
Class ManageTroubleTicket implements DeleteTicket?

What kind of strategy should I use?
Thanks for answering and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Is it not possible to simply add the methods `deleteTicket` and `modifyTicket` in the `ManageTroubleTicket` class ?

Comment: Sure, but what if I want to reuse the code?
E.G.
An operator from the other side of the app want to delete the ticket because is a fake (no gas loss).